# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'

Tags: python, opencv

I had some problems with Opencv in Python.

This attribute problem also happens with `imread`

I tried to uninstall and reinstall with contrib-Opencv,but it did not work.

About 2 months ago, my opencv file still worked well, but I don't know why it doesn't work now.

In the next reinstallations,this command always sastifies but no good results

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
...
cap.release()
```

My error command:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hoang Cao Chuyen\Documents\pyml\cv11.py", line 4, in <module>
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Hoang Cao Chuyen\Documents\pyml\cv11.py"]
```

Comment: hey, please copy your code into your question instead of including screenshots

Comment: i changed the form,please help me

Comment: If you use print(cv2.__version__) what does it print?

Comment: another question: how did you install opencv? what command did you use?

Comment: pip install opencv-python and pip install opencv-contrib-python.I tried many times but ...

Comment: @ChuyênHoàng what is the output of `print(cv2.__version__)`? Have you tried installing opencv with `python -m pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: the same issue happened to me when I stupidly named a file "copy.py"
please make sure you file names are not reserved python builtins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking my friend,i had the solution.It is very easy because i saved this file in Documents path in user which my private name Hoang Cao Chuyen without '_'.I changed into another path,and it was OK.

Answer (score 7):

One of the issue I noticed is that you used **cv11** as the main.py name.

It is very easy for PyCharm to get confused if you have a file saved as cv2.py. Please check if you have any other similar files with the name cv2.

Else, try to do this:

1. remove OpenCV
2. reinstall using command `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

OR

try reinstalling ffmpeg as it might be one of the issue

```
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

Comment: i tried to uninstall as you propose,but it still had errors

Comment: Would you mind sharing the complete error code in your question, so that more people understand the error details and can help you.

Comment: i added a picture about my error because i am not allowed to add a too long comment here

Comment: I also think is a problem with a filename. In the screenshot that you linked before I saw the directories included in your path, which are a lot. Try searching in these directories if there is a file named "cv2.py"

Comment: i changed the file name ,not cv2.py anymore but it is still error.Even a file i used 'imread',it also has attribute error

Comment: @ChuyênHoàng are you sure there aren't any other files named "cv2.py" (except the one of OpenCV) on your computer?

Comment: yes. i checked paths again as you said. No files vv2.py

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your file is called cv2.py so it imports itself and an error occurs, this can be understood from this line.

Most likely due to a circular import

Which translates as:

Most likely due to circular import

To fix the problem, rename your file

Comment: this is the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines:

```
from cv2 import VideoCapture
from cv2 import waitKey
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced issue in Python 3.9.2 with opencv-python-4.7.0.72.

Remove all opencv related libraries then installed it again. If need remove virtual environment then create virtual environment and install opencv.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

install

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: also this with the answer from @Nick is useful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was searching for ages. Finally I found a way that is (at least currently) working for me.

When installing opencv there will be a folder 'cv2' which again includes the package 'cv2'.

Installation directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\cv2
Package directory:  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\cv2\cv2

[Directory after installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnZiL.png)

Probably this leads to confusing for python (maybe some circular import or so). Therefore I just renamed the installation directory to something else, e.g. C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\cv2_

[Directory after renaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzTBr.png)

That is the solution that is currently (and hopefully in the future as well) working for me).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve all the problems of OPENCV-PYTHON is by uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Even I faced the same problem.

I fixed it by:

`python -m pip uninstall Opencv-python`

Then I reinstalled it by using a lower version. But unfortunately, I did not know the versions of opencv; So by using a small trick you can get it by running:

`python -m pip install opencv-python==`

and you will get an error similar to this:

```
.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.
4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==
```

Here you can see all the versions of opencv-python; choose any one (but not the latest as the error occurs due the latest version of opencv-python. install it by using:

`pip install opencv-python==3.4.17.61` (You can choose your version, but this version solved the issue for me)

then enjoy your coding....

Even AUTO-COMPLETE error in opencv-python gets solved.